# How to handle many-to-many link tables with additional columns

Tags: java, orm, jpa, eclipselink

Assume the following exemplary DB-Design:

```
USERS
-----------------
ID
NAME


ROLES
-----------------
ID
NAME


USERS_ROLES
-----------------
FK_USER_ID
FK_ROLE_ID
LOGIN
PASSWD
```

I map this relation with eclipse-link using xml.
The users:

```
<many-to-many name="roles" mapped-by="users">
  <join-table name="USERS_ROLES">
    <join-column name="USER_ID" />
    <inverse-join-column name="ROLE_ID" />
  </join-table>
</many-to-many>
```

For the sake of completeness, the corresponding mapping of the roles:

```
<many-to-many name="users" mapped-by="roles">
  <join-table name="USERS_ROLES">
    <join-column name="FK_ROLE_ID" />
    <inverse-join-column name="FK_USER_ID" />
  </join-table>
</many-to-many>
```

Now I could also create a mapping for the link-table, but what I have to do so that I can access the properties of the linked table (mapped to the java object/class)?
I need it if the users will login, choose their role of interest and enter the accordant password. With the current setup, of course, I can get all the roles the user is assigned to and vice versa, but I cannot compare against the login data, or any other properties corresponding to the relation of user and role.
In short: I have no clue how to access the properties of the linked table or how I have to map this in the mapping-xml.

Thx a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't an M-N though. It's 2 1-N's with an intermediate class (containing the login and password).

Comment: Thats the general way when the login information are bound to the users, but I need different login information for every user-role relation. So if the users want to login as role1 then they need to enter different login informations as well as they want to login as role2.

Comment: There are many ways you can do that with classes; I'm simply stating that it is not an M-N relation - there is no such Java container that allows attributes on a relation. Hence you split the attributes into an intermediate class, or have it as a related object off of Role.

Comment: Hm, sry but I can't agree with that. I guess I need a way to create a model/entity which map/represent the link-table with the additional attributes and bind it to the user and role entity. Thus I should have a way to get the information attached to the "link-entity" via the user/role combination. But I dunno how I should realize that binding with such a "link-entity".

Comment: I already told you to create an intermediate class to represent the attributes. As per http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/guides/jdo/many_many_attributed/index.html
If you don't want to then fine. It's a solution

Comment: Oh ok ... sry my fault. Thats what I'm search for. Thx a lot! I've also decided to use Annotations instead of the xml mappings. For the posterity I've also found an example to realize it with Eclipse-Link: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany#Mapping_a_Join_Table_with_Additional_Columns
Thx to DataNucleus!